# Reading a large text file in python kills my program

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote a python script to read in a text file and put its information in a Dictionary. The original text file is 2.6 gb and contains 56981936 lines, of these lines I only need to link every first line to its second and fourth in a dictionary. I recently switched from windows (were this program ran fine) to Linux, where it keeps getting killed. Does somebody have any idea why?

The text format is a fastQ file, which has repeating lines in the following format:

```
@xxxxxxxxxxx
CTTCTCAACTC
+
AAAEE#AEE#A
```

This is my original code:

```py
def createReverseDict(backwardsFile):
    reverseDict = {}
    with open(backwardsFile) as f3:
            while True:
                label       = f3.readline().rstrip()
                if not label:
                    break
                sequence    = f3.readline().rstrip()
                next(f3)
                score       = f3.readline().rstrip()
                reverseDict[label] = {"sequence" : sequence,
                                    "score"    : score   }
    return reverseDict
```

Comment: "Killed" usually means you're running out of memory. (See system logs, e.g. `journalctl`.) Does the machine have enough memory? Windows will happily start using swap memory, but Linux will not automagically configure swap for you.

Comment: Do you get an error message? What does it say?

Comment: @AKX I checken and when I run the programm my ram usage goes to 100% so it probably uses too much memory.. is this fixable? I have no idea what swap memory is ..

Comment: I checked the system logs and it says: jun 05 11:31:57 mark-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 2719 (python3) total-vm:6630708kB, anon-rss:6589852kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a small file that's 100MB (much smaller than yours but similar format) and used `namedtuple` to improve the memory performance. I also used tracemalloc to find out about how much memory was used.

```
import tracemalloc
tracemalloc.start()
createReverseDict("final.txt")
current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
print(f"Current memory usage is {current / 10**6}MB; Peak was {peak / 10**6}MB")
tracemalloc.stop()
```

With regular dictionaries here `reverseDict[label] = dict(sequence = sequence, score = score)`, my run had this

```
    Current memory usage is 0.020237MB; Peak was 1210.024309MB
```

By using `collections.namedtuple`, it reduces quite a bit. Almost by half.

```
    import collections
    item = collections.namedtuple('item', ['seq', 'sco'])
```

and

```
    reverseDict[label] = item(sequence, score)
```

inside the function. The memory usage dropped to

```
    Current memory usage is 0.003773MB; Peak was 760.651005MB
```

If you do this, perhaps the OOM killer will not kick in at all. If however, it does, you can use the details in [this link](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/dev-oom-killer.html) to  raise the OOM limits. Disabling it completely using

```
sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=2
```

I cannot vouch for how safe this is but you should be able to try it and once you're done reboot the system to get it back to defaults.